# C++ variadic template type filtering transformation

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

**Problem.**

I am new to template metaprogramming and am unsure of how to implement
a type filtering transformation on a tuple where a type is produced when provided
with a filtering description. I believe the following code snippet demonstrates
the behaviour I want.

```
enum : int {
  INCLUDE,
  EXCLUDE
};

template <int filter_val, class T>
struct filter {
};

int
main() {

  struct A {};
  struct B {};
  struct C {};

  typedef std::tuple<filter<INCLUDE, A>,
                     filter<EXCLUDE, B>,
                     filter<INCLUDE, C>> filters;

  typedef filter_all<filters>::type filtered;

  static_assert(std::is_same<filtered,
                             std::tuple<A, C>
                            >::value,
                ":(");

  return 0;
}
```

**What I've tried**

To my knowledge, you cannot unpack more than 1 independent variadic templates so the way I thought about approaching the problem is to maintain two tuples during the recursive template specialization process where one of them represents where we are in the recursion while the other represents the so-far included T's.

```
template <template <class ...> class, class ...Unfiltered_Ts>
struct filter_all {
private: 
  template <class Unfiltered_Ts_Tuple, class Included_Ts_Tuple>
  struct filter_all_impl;

  // CASE 1: Include T in the result
  template <
    template <int, class> class, int filter_val, class T, class ...Unfiltered_Ts_impl, // Unfiltered input
    template <class ...> class, class ...Included_Ts                                   // Result so far
  >
  struct filter_all_impl<std::tuple<filter<INCLUDE, T>,
                                    Unfiltered_Ts_impl...>,
                         std::tuple<Included_Ts...>> {
    typedef typename
      filter_all_impl<std::tuple<Unfiltered_Ts_impl...>,
                      std::tuple<Included_Ts..., T> // Append T to result
                     >::type type;
  };

  // CASE 2: Don't include T in the result
  template <
    template <int, class> class, int filter_val, class T, class ...Unfiltered_Ts_impl, // Unfiltered input
    template <class ...> class, class ...Included_Ts                                   // Result so far
  >
  struct filter_all_impl<std::tuple<filter<EXCLUDE, T>,
                                    Unfiltered_Ts_impl...>,
                         std::tuple<Included_Ts...>
                        > {
    typedef typename
      filter_all_impl<std::tuple<Unfiltered_Ts_impl...>,
                      std::tuple<Included_Ts...> // Don't append T to result
                     >::type type;
  };

  // CASE 3: Filtering finished - set the final type as the included T's
  template <
    template <int, class> class, int filter_val, class T, class ...Unfiltered_Ts_impl, 
    template <class ...> class, class ...Included_Ts
  >
  struct filter_all_impl<<>, // empty
                         std::tuple<Included_Ts...>
                        > {
    // Final step, set type as a tuple of all included Ts
    typedef std::tuple<Included_Ts...> type;
  };
public:
  typedef typename filter_all_impl<
    std::tuple<Unfiltered_Ts...>, // Initially contains all unfiltered Ts
    std::tuple<>                  // Initially empty filtered Ts which eventually becomes the return type
  >::type type;
};
```

I hope there is a simpler way to do this transformation but this is what I have arrived at so far but it's far from compiling and complains about the template specializations not being valid. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this question twice. Thanks for the clear explanation, test driver, and for showing your attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, define a `pick<T>` helper that returns an *empty tuple* for excluded items, and a *tuple containing the item* otherwise:

```
template <typename>
struct pick;

template <typename T>
struct pick<filter<INCLUDE, T>> { using type = std::tuple<T>; };

template <typename T>
struct pick<filter<EXCLUDE, T>> { using type = std::tuple<>; };
```

Then, implement your filtering logic in terms of `std::tuple_cat`:

```
template <typename>
struct filter_all;

template <typename... Ts>
struct filter_all<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{   
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(typename pick<Ts>::type{}...));
};
```

Done!

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2mpdcwQUDj2xb6LO)

---

If you can modify the implementation of `filter` to expose a `constexpr bool`, it can be even simpler:

```
template <int filter_val, class T>
struct filter 
{
    static constexpr bool pick = filter_val == INCLUDE;
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct filter_all;

template <typename... Ts>
struct filter_all<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{   
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::conditional_t<Ts::pick, 
            std::tuple<typename Ts::type>, std::tuple<>>{}...
    ));
};
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s2mb2JNqGGpwMdjM)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm glad my mess didn't compile because this will be a lot easier to manage. Although I wonder if I was somewhere on the right path to getting it to do the right thing, despite its ugliness...

Comment: `T` might be not default constructible (and so `tuple<T>`), so you should replace `pick<Ts>::type{}` by `std::declval<pick<Ts>::type>`.